# Set a Datetime index in a DataFrame with multiple Datetime columns with different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with different datatime columns, each one next to a "value" column, which contains values measured at every datetime. As you can see, some values are not measured at every second:

| Datetime 1 | Value 1 | Datetime 2 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:00 | 2 | 01.01.2023 10:00:00 | 5 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:01 | 10 | 01.01.2023 10:00:03 | 1 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:02 | 15 | 01.01.2023 10:00:06 | 10 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:03 | 6 | 01.01.2023 10:00:07 | 8 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:04 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:05 | 10 | NaN | NaN |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:06 | 15 | NaN | NaN |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:07 | 6 | NaN | NaN |

**My goal is to obtain a DataFrame with only one datetime column as index (for instance Datetime1), and to make all "value" columns match it. For the non-existent values I would like to input the last registered value.**

For example, I would like to obtain this as my resulting DataFrame:

| Datetime 1 | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:00 | 2 | 5 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:01 | 10 | 5 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:02 | 15 | 5 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:03 | 6 | 1 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:04 | 2 | 1 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:05 | 10 | 1 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:06 | 15 | 10 |
| 01.01.2023 10:00:07 | 6 | 8 |

Another option that would interest me is doing the opposite: setting my Datetime 2 column as index and deleting extra rows.

Keep in mind that this is a simplified example. I have at least 10 datetime-value column pairs in my dataframe. **I would like to either set the longest one or the shortest one as index.**

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot !

Python 3.11.2

Comment: What are the empty values? NaN, empty strings?

Comment: NaN, sorry I forgot to specify.

Comment: It's important for you to get integer values for Value 2 (or Value 1)?

Comment: No, it can be other number format like float. As long as values are numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a left merge here:

```
(df.iloc[:,:2]
   .rename({'Datetime 1': 'Datetime'}, axis=1)
   .merge(df.iloc[:,2:].rename({'Datetime 2': 'Datetime'}, axis=1), how='left')
   .ffill())

             Datetime  Value 1  Value 2
0 2023-01-01 10:00:00        2        5
1 2023-01-01 10:00:01       10        5
2 2023-01-01 10:00:02       15        5
3 2023-01-01 10:00:03        6        1
4 2023-01-01 10:00:04        2        1
5 2023-01-01 10:00:05       10        1
6 2023-01-01 10:00:06       15       10
7 2023-01-01 10:00:07        6        8
```

The idea is to take the first two columns and perform a left merge with the last two columns. Then finally forward fill missing values.

I've renamed the Datetime columns so there's only one datetime column in the output. If you want to be explicit, you could also specify `on='Datetime'` while merging.

---

When the number of columns are not known in advance, you can still slice by pairs of two and do an index based `join`:

```
df_list = [
    (df.iloc[:,i:i+2]
       .set_index(df.columns[i])
       .rename_axis('Datetime')) 
    for i in range(0, df.shape[1], 2)
]
(df_list[0].join(df_list[1:])
           .dropna(axis=0, how='all')
           .ffill()
           .reset_index())

             Datetime  Value 1  Value 2
0 2023-01-01 10:00:00        2        5
1 2023-01-01 10:00:01       10        5
2 2023-01-01 10:00:02       15        5
3 2023-01-01 10:00:03        6        1
4 2023-01-01 10:00:04        2        1
5 2023-01-01 10:00:05       10        1
6 2023-01-01 10:00:06       15       10
7 2023-01-01 10:00:07        6        8
```

`df.join` supports merging multiple DataFrames at once, so is preferred for this kind of operation.

Comment: Thanks for the respone! That makes sense. Then I should iterate the process by adding a merge for every 2 columns of the dataframe right? Since my df has about 20 columns.

Comment: @Perrupi that would work but I would recommend a more robust approach that generalized for multiple dfs. Please check my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.concat` and `reduce` from functools:

```
from functools import reduce

def concat(left, right):
    left = left[1].dropna().set_index(left[1].columns[0])
    right = right[1].dropna().set_index(right[1].columns[0])
    return pd.concat([left, right], axis=1).rename_axis('Datetime').reset_index()

g = df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 2, axis=1)
out = reduce(concat, g).ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
              Datetime  Value 1  Value 2
0  01.01.2023 10:00:00        2      5.0
1  01.01.2023 10:00:01       10      5.0
2  01.01.2023 10:00:02       15      5.0
3  01.01.2023 10:00:03        6      1.0
4  01.01.2023 10:00:04        2      1.0
5  01.01.2023 10:00:05       10      1.0
6  01.01.2023 10:00:06       15     10.0
7  01.01.2023 10:00:07        6      8.0
```

Comment: I updated my answer to work with any (Datetime X, Value X) columns.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! And it works independently of the name of the Datetime columns.